# Turn autocomplete off with rails form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, autocomplete, autofill

I'm trying to turn autocomplete off in one of my rails forms. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
# add it at the form level
= form_tag admin_sessions_path, autocomplete: "off" do
```

That didn't work.

```
# add it at the element level
.panel
  = label_tag :email
  = email_field_tag :email, params[:email], autocomplete: 'off'
```

Neither did that.

```
# add it to both
= form_tag admin_sessions_path, autocomplete: "off" do

  # add it at the element level
  .panel
    = label_tag :email
    = email_field_tag :email, params[:email], autocomplete: 'off'
```

When I visit my form, my email address and saved password are already filled-in. What am I doing wrong here? I love rails, but it really drives me mad sometimes.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As of Rails 4+

Disable autocomplete for an entire form with `form_tag`:

```
= form_tag admin_sessions_path, html: { autocomplete: "off" } do
```

Disable autocomplete for an entire form with `form_for`:

```
= form_for @user, html: { autocomplete: "off" } do |f|
```

Disable autocomplete for a single form element:

```
= f.text_field :foo, autocomplete: 'off'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great timing - I posted this question (or similar) yesterday and only just found your answer today. Works perfectly - thanks!

Comment: Glad it was helpful. :-)

Comment: @MattSanders using `html` wasn't working for me and after reading the docs state `Any other key creates standard HTML attributes for the tag`, I just removed the `html` and simply had `form_tag my_path { autocomplete: "off" }`, which worked for me

Comment: @Marklar - thanks for the update. What version of rails are you using? The behavior may have changed in newer versions.

Comment: 5.1 [docs reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)

Comment: I always forget to use the `html: {}` hash to set the option. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

the autocomplete attribute should be assigned to the html key like so:

```
html: {autocomplete: 'off'}
```

Answer (score 5):

In latest version of chrome `autocomplete: 'off'` does not work. Instead use `autocomplete: 'disabled'`

Comment: _NOTE: In Internet Explorer: "Any string other than off enables AutoComplete."_

Comment: Also, _"As of Internet Explorer 11, the autocomplete property is no longer supported for input type=password fields."_

Answer (score 1):

There several ways of turning off the autocomplete functionality:

**On form level:** (autoceomplete turned of for all inputs)

```
<% form_tag(:form_name, @form_name, autocomplete = "off") do |f|%>
```

**Per input:**

```
<%= text_field_tag('my input', nil, autocomplete = 'off') %>
```

**Simple Form per input:**

```
<% f.text_field :fieldname, input_html: {autocomplete: 'off'} %>
```

Comment: Thanks but none of those options work with form_tag. The first and third suggestions work with form_for (and derivatives like simple_form), and the second one generates the following html: `<input id="email" name="email" options="{:autocomplete=>&quot;off&quot;}" type="email">`. The docs for form_tag show that there is not option called :options.

Comment: Sorry... There is no option called :options, you're absolutly right. Just add your additional attributes like in my edited version. This way you're even able to add "foo='bar'. Same for the form_tag... 
See API Documentation:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag

Comment: Ha, your new suggestions cause rails to throw an exception :) `autocomplete = 'off'` is valid html, but not ERB or HAML. Anyway, I think I must have done something funny, like save my password before turning autocomplete off. Perhaps I will have some luck if I delete my saved passwords and try again with autocomplete off from the start. Thanks again.

Comment: Hehe... Okay. But as described in the documentation it supposed to work by adding additional options in a row with simple "equals'. I have no project using form_tag so I had to sort of guess. I appreciate the convenience of form_for or formtastic. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Unfortunately, this method has drawbacks

1. Fields are not filled back after validation errors and `render :xxx`

- solution to this issue is to make `alias_attribute :c_ountry, :country`, but personally I don't like the hackyness of it

2. Method does not work on English locale (at least for me), but works on other locales

**Edit 2:**
Ultimately I solved it with a combination of three approaches which I described in [more general question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65364999/6148582)

**Original answer:**

It's the fault of HTML and mostly Chrome, not Rails.

As of **December 2020** and **Chrome 87** all of the above solutions didn't worked for me, neither do many variations from the web with `autocomplete`, `readonly`, `onclick`, `type`, etc. attributes' workarounds.

Solution to prevent **Autofill**

What worked is to not name the field with their full names. i.e. if we have country and city fields, then instead of this

```rb
= f.text_field :country
= f.text_field :city
```

do this

```rb
= f.text_field :c_ountry
= f.text_field :cit_y
```

Then manually reassign params in controller. i.e.

```rb
def user_params
  params[:user][:country] = params[:user].delete(:c_ountry)
  params[:user][:city] = params[:user].delete(:cit_y)

  params.require(:user).permit(:country, :city)
end
```

**Gotcha:**
I noted that Chrome is triggering autofill also when it finds other words in `type`. For example, I observed that this triggers autofill

```rb
= f.text_field :d_istrict
```

while this don't trigger autofill

```rb
= f.text_field :d_istric_t
```