# how stop Chrome use password for

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have work on project that has many password fields, I tried to use `autocomplete = "off"` but not work , and then use `autocomplete = "new-password"` it was working but suddenly it is stopped work and get this image

[image]

how can I stop this in `Chrome`?

dose new version of Chrome have bug ?!

It isn't appeared  in `Firefox`, `IE` or `Edge`.

Comment: I believe this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill).

Comment: I have read this answers but it was worked correct on `chrome`, `Firefox` and `Edge` , but now it is worked  on `Firefox` and `Edge` only

Comment: Are you using input `type="password"`? Believe that is needed for `autocomplete = "off"` to work correctly/

Comment: I used  Solution 3 in   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200130/how-to-disable-chrome-to-autofill-username-email-password/#answer-40200269